# GNU Make - Extracting job parameters and passing it to another process

Tags: makefile

This is what I'm trying to do in my Makefile:

```
MAKE_381 := $(TOOLS)/bin/make-381

default:
    cd proj && $(MAKE_381)
```

`MAKE_381` refers to the version of `make v3.81` binary. This is required since the `proj` directory contains `Makefiles` which are compatible only with `v3.81` and nothing newer or older.

I need to have this Makefile always use `make v3.81` to build `proj` independent of the version of GNU make the developer has installed on his/her system.

Invoking `MAKE_381` works but with one caveat, any extra parameters like number of parallel jobs, are not passed to `MAKE_381`. I could not find any documentation on how to extract this information.

I'm aware of `MAKEFLAGS` variable in GNU make, which I understand should contain any extra parameters passed to make from command line, but somehow I find this value to be empty.

I do not wish to hardcode the number of jobs passed to `MAKE_381`, instead the parameter should be passed through based on the initial `Makefile` invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is prefix the command line with a `+` character, so make knows that you're invoking another sub-make process:

```
default:
        + cd proj && $(MAKE_381)
```

If your command used the variable `MAKE` directly then this would be automatic, but since you're using a different variable name (`MAKE_381`), you have to do it explicitly.